# Watch element value in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to create a directive that i want to use like so:

```
<div before-today="old">{{exampleDate}}</div>
```

I want my directive to determine if the date inside the div is before "today", and if so, apply the class "old". My main problem is that "exampleDate" gets populated from an AJAX call, so at link time the value is empty. Any suggestions? This is what I have so far (not working):

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('beforeToday', [
  function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
    scope: {

    },
      link: function (scope, element, attr) {
        var date = new Date(element.text());
        var today = new Date();
        if (today >= date) {
          element.addClass(attr.beforeToday);
        }
      } 
    };
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
<div before-today="old" watch-me="exampleDate" >{{exampleDate}}</div>
```

**Directive**

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('beforeToday', [
  function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',   
      link: function (scope, element, attr) {


        scope.$watch(attr.watchMe,function(newValue,oldValue){
                //check new value to be what you expect.
             if (newValue){           
                  var date = new Date(element.text());
                  var today = new Date();
                  if (today >= date) {
                    element.addClass(attr.beforeToday);
                  } 
             }
        });
      } 
    };
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than writing your own custom directive, why not make use of Angular's built-in [`ngClass`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)?

**HTML**

```
<div ng-class="{'beforeToday': detectDate('2013-11-10') }"> text here </div>
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.detectDate = function(input){
  var date = new Date(input);
  var today = new Date();
  if (today >= date)
     return true;
  else
     return false;
}
```

`ngClass` is great. You pass in an object, the key is the class to conditionally add/remove, the value is the expression to evaluate. In this example I'm passing in a function. But you could also do the expression inline. But putting it in the controller would be more maintainable long term.